# Application installation does not work after auto-update

Tags: nvidia, cuda

My system (Ubuntu 18) was applied automatic updates. And now I can't install anything. Mostly there were updates for CUDA.
Erorr code:

```
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libcublas-dev_10.1.0.105-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tryed:

**sudo apt --fix-broken install**

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libcublas-dev_10.1.0.105-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/cublas_v2.h', which is also in package nvidia-cuda-dev 9.1.85-3ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libcublas-dev_10.1.0.105-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix it?